# pthread_mutex_lock can't acquire lock

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, mutex, mmap

There are two applications: one sending signals and one receiving them. I want to share mutex, conditional variable and flag between these two applications. My solution using mmap works with only one receiving process, but after I add more, I can't acquire lock, that seems free.

I have no ideas how to fix this, but I'm almost sure the problem is in my way of sharing mutex through mmap.

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    int flags[MAX_PROCS];
    int ready[MAX_PROCS];
} cb;
```

Code for sending signals:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, fd, ret;
    char handle = '\n';

    pthread_mutexattr_t attrmutex;
    pthread_condattr_t attrcond;

    fd = shm_open("tmp", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(cb));
    cb *control = (cb*)mmap(NULL,
                            sizeof(cb),
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                            MAP_SHARED,
                            fd,
                            0);
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrmutex);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attrmutex, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(&control->mutex, &attrmutex);
    pthread_condattr_init(&attrcond);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&attrcond, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_cond_init(&control->cond, &attrcond);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PROCS; i++) {
        control->flags[i] = 0;
        control->ready[i] = 0;
    }

    while (handle != 'q') {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%c", &handle);
        if (handle == 'p' || handle == 'P') {
            for (i = 0; i < MAX_PROCS; i++) {
                if (!control->ready[i])
                    printf("Process %d doesn't exist\n", i);
                else
                    printf("Process %d listening\n", i);
            }
        }
        else if (isdigit(handle)) {
            i = atoi(&handle);
            printf("Signal sent\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&control->mutex);
            control->flags[i]++;
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&control->cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&control->mutex);
        }
        else {
            printf("Choose process(es) to signal\n");
            printf("P to print attached proceses\n");
            printf("CTRL-C to quit\n");
        }
        if (handle != '\n')
            scanf("%c", &handle);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Code for receiving signals:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, fd, br;
    char handle = '\n';

    fd = shm_open("tmp", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(cb));
    cb *control = (cb*)mmap(NULL,
                            sizeof(cb),
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                            MAP_SHARED,
                            fd,
                            0);

    br = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PROCS; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&control->mutex);
        if(!control->ready[i]) {
            control->ready[i]++;
            br++;
        }
        else
            printf("Process %d exists\n", i);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&control->mutex);
        if (br)
            break;
    }

    printf("Process %d listening\n", i);

    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&control->mutex);
        while (control->flags[i] == 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&control->cond, &control->mutex);
        }
        printf("Signal received!\n");
        control->flags[i]--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&control->mutex);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

As my listening processes enter waiting state, mutex should be free to acquire by sending process, but it just blocks.

P.S. When I start second receiving process pthread_cond_wait returns EINVAL error (wrong arguments). First two processes just deadlock on wait and broadcast functions. Somehow, sharing memory with one more process ruins mutex and conditional variable stored in shared memory.

Comment: "*no ideas how to fix this*" the 1st thing is to add complete error checking and logging to **all** relevant function calls.

Comment: Caught the error, seems to be shared memory problem. Can't fix it though

Comment: At least here `for (i = 0; i < MAX_PROCS; i++) {
                if (!control->ready[i])` concurrent access to the control-flags may happen unprotected. Fix this by using the mutex around reading them here as well.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, but thanks, fixed it